# Grub not loading?

Tags: 11.10, installation, grub2

So I got fed up with Windows Vista and decided to install Ubuntu. My roommate has the 11.10 version and so that is what I installed. I've used Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10 on a different computer before so I thought I wouldn't have any problems. Well, after I wiped the Hard drive it started installing Ubuntu. It restarted and when it restarted the BIOS window came up. Then, after the BIOS loaded it just has a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left and stays that way. GRUB doesn't even come up so I can't do anything. I've already googled it and I have not been able to find an answer. Anybody know what's up? I could just simply reinstall it but I'm guessing the same thing will happen.

Comment: If Ubuntu is the only OS on a system I believe that GRUB does not display its menu *unless* you press and hold the shift key immediately after the BIOS display ends. Please try that to see if the GRUB menu displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the live cd/usb booted correctly?

If so,try reinstalling `GRUB`.
Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

There are many other option to play with, since you don't care about re-installation.

More information can be found here- > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: this may also helps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: he just wiped out everything, so why windows again!! :P

Comment: let vista wiped forever, i guess he may get interested in win7 later. :P

Comment: and make this topic favirate as well :D

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I didn't completely wipe the drive so Windows would load without ever showing GRUB. I ended up fixing the problem by running [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the live USB I was using to install Ubuntu (12.04 in my case).