# how to get  ubuntu on  bootloader

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have install C Drive window 7 and E driver Ubuntu. It works fine, when first time rum my computer it comes boot loader(choosing option) which OS do you want run. But some problem in my window 7, after that problem, I format window 7 but boot loader doesn't comes.

So, How to get Ubuntu in boot loader.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? A possible duplicate but won't know until we know more about the version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137184/grub-not-loading (this is for 11.10)

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu! I have to say that your question is a little complicated to understand. Could you please give more details about what you see when you start your computer? Can you now boot into Windows? Can you boot into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Boot Repair to fix your bootloader.

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Repair the bootloader

To restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now, with both Windows and Ubuntu appearing in the Grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Installing Windows removed GRUB.
Somehow run Ubuntu (e.g. using Live CD) and install GRUB.

## Long answer

### Boot process

From Wikipedia:

> When a computer is turned on, the computer’s BIOS finds the primary
> bootable device (usually the computer’s hard disk) and loads the
> initial bootstrap program from the master boot record (MBR), the first
> 512 bytes of the hard disk, then transfers control to the bootstrap
> code.

So, [what happened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128233/windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-dual-boot-grub-not-showing)?

> What happens is that Uncle Bill does not accept that any other
> operating system (O/S) apart from one created by Microsoft should be
> allowed to run on a PC. So, when you load / re-load any of Uncle
> Bill’s O/Ss it will overwrite a part of your hard disk called the
> Master Boot Record (mbr). This is the bit that tells your PC, during
> boot up, where to find the operating system.

### Solution

#### Somehow run Ubuntu

(e.g. using [usb flash drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick))

#### Install/repair GRUB

Locate Linux partition using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Mount the partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/boot
```

Install GRUB:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
```

Where X is drive letter (e.g. a, b, c).

Update GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

after installing. Reboot system and GRUB menu should be loaded.