# laptop won't detect any bootable device and go straight to the bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So I have 2 disk in my laptop the first disk for the windows an the second one for linux, after formatting the disk that contain windows the Linux still working untill I restart my laptop, it won't detect any bootable device, so right now I'm stuck at bios, is there any way to fix it or I must reinstall linux

Comment: Temporarily disconnect the cable to the disk that has Windows installed on it,, Then the BIOS will work normally again allowing you to change the boot priority of the bootable USB device.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details (Linux is vague), but it reads to me like you need to change the boot order in uEFI/BIOS setup to boot from the other disk; doing this is device specific (ie. *your device's firmware controls how easy/difficult this is for your unstated OS*)

Comment: If the above comments do not help please [try these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/138087/512236). Essentially boot from an Ubuntu live CD, you may have one on a USB Stick that you used to install Ubuntu, install the boot repair program and run the suggested commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)